# Data Analytics vs Data Science vs Data Mining vs Data Analysis

Tags: data-mining, data-analysis

I've come across multiple definitions of these terms and couldn't able to get the actual meaning of what exactly is.

From someone with experience, what exactly Data Analytics, Data Science, Data Mining, Data Analysis is about? I know they all relate to Data but can someone explain in detail?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for definitions of terms, not about a programming question as defined by the [help]. Perhaps ask on the English Language & Usage site where single-term definition requests are on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

**Data Analytics:** Data analytics focuses on processing and performing statistical analysis on existing datasets by concentrating on building methods to capture and organize data to reveal actionable insights for ongoing problems and finding the best way to present this data.

- Scope: Micro
- Goal: To find actionable data
- Major Fields: Gaming, Travel, Healthcare, Industries with
  immediate data needs.
- Tools: R, Tableau Public, Python, SAS, Apache Spark, Excel are used.

**Data Science:** Data science is a multidisciplinary field concentrated on finding actionable insights from large sets of raw and structured data. Data science experts use several different techniques to obtain answers, incorporating computer science, predictive analytics and machine learning to parse through large datasets in an effort to create solutions to problems that haven’t been considered yet.

- Scope: Macro
- Goal: To ask the right questions
- Major Fields: Machine learning, AI, Search Engine,
  Corporate analytics.
- Tools: Jupyter, Matplotlib, Scikit-Learn, NLTK, TensorFlow, SAS,
  Apache Spark, Matlab, Excel, D3.js, BigML, ggplot2, Weka

**Data Mining:** It refers to the extraction of useful information from bulk data or data warehouses. The result of data mining is the patterns and knowledge that we gain at the end of the extraction process. Data Mining is also known as Knowledge Discovery or Knowledge Extraction. Data mining is the computational process of analyzing data from a different perspective, angles or dimensions and categorizing it into meaningful information.

- Scope: Macro
- Goal: To build a predictive model.
- Major Fields: AI, corporate analytics.
- Tools: R, Rapid Miner, Orange, Knime, DataMelt, Apache Mahout, ELKI,
  MOA, KEEL, Rattle.

**Data Analysis:** Data analysis is a specialized form of data analytics used in businesses to analyze data and take some insights. The sequence followed in data analysis are data gathering, data scrubbing, analysis of data and intercept the data precisely so that you understand what your data want to say.

- Scope: Macro
- Goal: To find actionable data
- Major Fields: Healthcare, Gaming, Travel, Corporate Firms.
- Tools: Knime, Rapid Miner, Google Fusion Tables, Tableau Public,
  NODEXL, WOLFRAM Alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Different people.

Using different favorite buzzwords.

All processing data in one way or another.

Some versions (analytics) are mostly popular with non-academic business bllsht bingo. Data science is totally overloaded business nonsense now, too.

In the end, it matters what you do, not how you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I agree above Anony's statement, try to define in the academic ways :

Data Science   :

> Set of fundamental Principles that guide the extraction of knowledge
>   of  data.

Data Analysis  :

> Refer to activities the aim to explain past behavior.

Data Analytics :

> Explore the data for potential future events.

Data Mining    :

> The practice of examining large pre-existing databases in order to
>   generate new information.